# How can I see the source code for a demo on SwiperJS.com? Link below

Tags: swiper.js

I'm having a problem finding the source code for this demo:

https://swiperjs.com/demos#css-mode

I think the website may have changed a bit because looking at youtube tutorial, they was a button there for source code which has now disappeared... Thankful for help

Answer (score 1):

You should go to https://swiperjs.com/ then click on the github icon found on their website which will redirect you to their github repo.Click on their demo repo and choose css-mode.html to get the source code